# Is there a way to create a new blob as a folder using logic apps?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-blob-storage

I've set up a logic app to move my new files on my FTP server to my azure storage container, which has blobs for my files. I found a way to create new folders using the storage explorer, but is there a way I can automate this using logic apps? For example, if a new folder is created in my FTP and files are added to it, I want to create a blob folder and move those files into that blob.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, Azure blob storage  **doesn't support folders**. There is only your storage account and a list of container containing blobs.

What you can do is to **simulate** a directory by adding a name that contains a slash, e. g. uploading the following file:

```
/myVirtualFolder/test.txt
```

Will upload the file to your desired container and tools like storage explorer will parse the slashes and display them as a folder:

[image]

But if you check the metadata for test.txt, you will see that the actual file name is `/myVirtualFolder/test.txt`:

[image]

So all you have to do is to upload all your files from your target directory to the container by adding the virtual directory to its name. You can`t and don't have to create a folder first.

Comment: If I do `Create Blob` in my logic app and put a container name (that did not exist) in the blob name property I got an error: `Specified blob tmp/log1.txt does not exist.` If I put the container name in the folder path property I got the error: `Specified container tmp does not exist.`. Have you done this with an Logic App or does it work only with the Storage Explorer?

Comment: @zgue Sorry, not tested it with logic app yet. Maybe you have to create the container (a blob names tmp) first?

Comment: Thanks I will try it